# Use JQuery-functions on a DOM-element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I do believe this is a very stupid question and there's a very simple answer for it, but I didn't found a solution:

I have the following JavaScript function:

```
function setStatus(order, operation, status, elem){
    elem.parent().$(".active").removeClass("active");
    elem.addClass("active");
}
```

Elem is Image-element in my HTML which I'm sure is the right one by checking it's type with `alert(elem);`

The error I get is exactly what I expected:

> Object #< HTMLImageElement> has no method 'parent'

I already know this is because elem is a DOM-element and not an JQuery-element which means that it's not possible to use functions like `parent()` and `addClass()`. How can I use all JQuery-function on my elem? Is there a way to convert a DOM-element to a JQuery-element? I found this question on the internet many times with `this` that should have been `$(this)`, but `$(elem)` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `$(elem).siblings().removeClass("active").end().addClass("active");`...?

Comment: why are you using `$(".active")` ?

Comment: `$(".active", $(elem).parent()).removeClass("active");
$(elem).addClass("active");` 

alert() isn't the best way to log/debug code. Use instead console.log($(elem));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
function setStatus(order, operation, status, elem){
    elem.parent().find(".active").removeClass("active");
    elem.addClass("active");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$(elem).parent().removeClass("active");
 $(elem).addClass("active");
```

remove `$(".active")`. i think this is also culprit.

Comment: that does the trick! But how must I remove al "actives" from the elements with classname active now?

Comment: `$(".active").removeClass("active");` add this line at the start of code. ghope it will work

Comment: well, that's not quite the same as I wanted to do, the function has to remove all "actives" from the elements with classname active in the parent of elem. Your code will remove "active" the parent, not for the elements WITHIN parent

Comment: i was on lunch... i am glad you find your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

`.parent()` is a jquery function so in order to use it, you must "jqueryify" the element you are working with, so:

```
$(elem)
```

also, the spurious `$('.active')` would cause issues so the solution should be:

```
$(elem).parent().removeClass("active");
```

However, without seeing some HTML to go along with the JS, I can't be 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors in your script and you can use this `.addback()` to chain it.

```
elem.parent(".active").removeClass("active").addBack().addClass("active");
```